# How to show Validation Summary in a modal form with ajax post method?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I'm beginner in ASP.NET Core MVC. I have a problem in my website code.

My model is `User` that has some fields, and I wrote a view model based on these fields.

I've written the following code:

My view model: `RegisterViewModel`:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter {0} value please.")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "{0} Shouldn't have more than {1} Characters")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter {0} value please.")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} Shouldn't have more than {1} Characters")]
    public string Password { get; set; } 
}
```

My controller: `AccountController`:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private IUser _iuser;

    public AccountController(IUser iuser)
    {
        _iuser = iuser;
    }

    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel register)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_iuser.isUsernameExist(register.Username))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "This User Exists!");
                return PartialView(register);
            }
            else
            {
                User user = new User()
                {
                    Username = register.Username,
                    Password = HashGenerators.EncodingPassWithMD5(register.Password),
                    RoleId = 2,
                };

                _iuser.AddUser(user);
                string TabName = "UserTab";
                return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Profile", new {TabName}) });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView(register);
        }
    }
}
```

Register action has a view that has displayed as a modal.

View `Register.cshtml`:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <hr />
    <form asp-action="Register">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger text-right"></div>          
        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" , placeholder="username" id="txtUsername"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger" id="ValidationSummery"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" , placeholder="password" id="txtPassword"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger text-right" id="ValidationSummery"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" value="Create" onclick='AddUser()' class="btn-red pull-left" />
            <button href="#" type="button" onclick='ClearForm()' class="btn-red pull-right"> Clear Form </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Modal code (at the end of above code):

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div id="bodyModal" class="modal-body">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and at the end of view, I have these Ajax scripts:

```
<script>
function ClearForm() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/Register/",
        type: "Get",
        data: {}
    }).done(function (result) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#bodyModal').html(result);
    });
    $('#myModal').modal('dispose'); }
</script>
<script>
function AddUser() {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Account/Register/",
    type: "Post",
    data: {
        Username: $("#txtUsername").val(),
        Password: $("#txtPassword").val(),
    },
    success: function (response) {
        window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;
    }
}).done(function (result) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#bodyModal').html(result);
});}
</script>
```

When program is running, the `ClearForm` button works well, the `Create` button works well when modelstate is valid. But when modelstate is not valid, it goes to an error page (Hello world!), I see validation errors for 1 second but browser opens an wrong page and doesn't stay on modal for showing validation error.

NOTE: When I delete: ( window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;) from ajax AddUser function at success part, modal stays open and validation errors displays. But if modelstate is valid, modal stays open but it was empty and destination page(Index/Profile#UserTab) doesn't display.

Please help me, how can I change above code to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inspiring help of https://stackoverflow.com/users/11965297/mj1313, I Changed my code like following and my problem is solved entirely...

In controller, I send a parameter(Valid) by ViewBag to my view, to specify ModelState validity status.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel register)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (_iuser.isUsernameExist(register.Username))
        {
            ViewBag.Valid= "1"; // It's part of my change
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "This User Exists!");
            return PartialView(register);
        }
        else
        {
            User user = new User()
            {
                Username = register.Username,
                Password = HashGenerators.EncodingPassWithMD5(register.Password),
                RoleId = 2,
            };

            _iuser.AddUser(user);
            ViewBag.Valid= "0"; // It's part of my change
            string TabName = "UserTab";
            return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Profile", new {TabName}) });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Valid= "1"; // It's part of my change
        return PartialView(register);
    }
}
```

And in My view, I use a hidden input for save ViewBag.

```
<form asp-action="Register">

    <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Valid" /> @*It's part of my change*@
    
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger text-right"></div>          
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" , placeholder="username" 
    </div>
     .....
</form>
```

At the end, I change Ajax function, success part:

```
function AddUser() {
   $.ajax({
       url: "/Account/Register/",
       type: "Post",
       data: {
            Username: $("#txtUsername").val(),
            Password: $("#txtPassword").val(),
       },
       success: function (response) {
            $('#bodyModal').html(response);
            var isValid = $('body').find('[name="IsValid"]').val();
            if (isValid) {
                 $('#myModal').modal('show');
             } else {
                 window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;
             }           
       }
 }).done(function (result) {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      $('#bodyModal').html(result);
 });}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can have a new partial view to show the validation message.

Add a hidden input field to the partial view:

```
<input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
```

Then in ajax success function determine whether to show the modal or redirect by judging the value of `IsValid`

A simple demo based on your codes.

**Register.cshtml:**

```
@model RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h1>Register</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <hr />
        <form asp-action="Register">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger text-right"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" , placeholder="username" id="txtUsername" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger" id="ValidationSummery"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" , placeholder="password" id="txtPassword" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger text-right" id="ValidationSummery"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" value="Create" onclick='AddUser()' class="btn-red pull-left" />
                <button href="#" type="button" onclick='ClearForm()' class="btn-red pull-right"> Clear Form </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="bodyModal" class="modal-body">
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{

    <script>
        function AddUser() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Account/Register/",
                type: "Post",
                data: {
                    Username: $("#txtUsername").val(),
                    Password: $("#txtPassword").val(),
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#bodyModal').html(response);
                    var isValid = $('body').find('[name="IsValid"]').val() == 'True';
                    if (!isValid) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    } else {
                        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Profile")";
                    }
                
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

**_Register.cshtml(Partial View):**

```
@model RegisterViewModel

<form asp-action="Register">
    <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger text-right"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" , placeholder="username" id="txtUsername" readonly />
        <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger" id="ValidationSummery"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" , placeholder="password" id="txtPassword" readonly />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger text-right" id="ValidationSummery"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel register)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // do some stuff
        }

        return PartialView("_Register",register);
        
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But Register view is a modal itself. and I can't want open another modal. In your example, register view is a full view.

Comment: When I tested your suggestion code,  isValid value is always false! (in my code that register view is modal view)